# Testing multipart/form-data in with Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn

Tags: forms, http, elixir

Here is the sample code I am working with:

```
@body """
  --13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="exists"

  overwrite
  --13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="10.jpg"
  Content-Type: image/jpeg

  <content>
  --13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f--
  """

test "a test" do
  headers = [
    {"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f"},
    {"Content-Length", byte_size(@body)}
  ]
  conn = %Plug.Conn{req_headers: headers}
  |> Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn.conn(:post, "/a/post/path", @body)

  IO.puts "Conn headers: #{inspect conn.req_headers}"
  IO.puts "Conn adapter body:\n #{elem(conn.adapter, 1).req_body}\n-------------------------"
  IO.puts "Conn body_params before Parser: #{inspect conn.body_params}"
  conn = Plug.Parsers.call(conn, Plug.Parsers.init(parsers: [Plug.Parsers.MULTIPART],  pass: ["*/*"]))
  IO.puts "Conn body_params after Parser: #{inspect conn.body_params}"
end
```

And here is the output in the console:

```
Conn headers: [{"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f"}, {"Content-Length", 263}]
Conn adapter body:
 --13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="exists"

overwrite
--13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="10.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<content>
--13eba0c1a6344d0ca6850a87303ced0f--

-------------------------
Conn body_params before Parser: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :body_params}
Conn body_params after Parser: %{}
```

From what I understand about the format of a multipart/form-data request, this should parse out into a map containing the "file" and "exists" keys. When I make real POST requests against my Plug-based server, the requests are correctly parsed and body_params contains a map with the expected keys.

Is this a case of a mal-formed post body format? Is this a flaw / limitation in the  Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn code? Am I doing something wrong in a subtle way when I parse the Conn?

I can test this interface by directly passing mock'd pre-parsed Conn structures, but I would rather not do that.

Comment: I can't give you an exact answer but have you tried doing a form with multipart without being in a test case? I've done it before and if I recall correctly (can't check right now) you should have a field Plug.upload that has the expected keys.